# Algorithms for bidirectional graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path, minimum-spanning-tree

Say I have a graph (network) of nodes, with weightings on the following:
1. travelling one way on a link between two nodes.
2. travelling the other way on a link between two nodes (these might be different).
3. changing from one link to another.

Also, some of the nodes are one-way only.

In this case, what would be the best algorithms for:
a) finding a minimum spanning tree
b) finding the shortest route between two nodes
c) finding the "travelling salesman" path (i.e. the shortest route that goes everywhere, with minimum duplication)?

Also, would it be best to treat the bi-directional thing as two single-directional paths, rather than a bidirectional path with different weightings in each direction?

---an example---

```
              3
  A --<2/3>-- B --<3/2>-- C
  | 1        2|3
  |           |
  ^1/4       ^4/3
  |           |
  |3         4|
8 D --<3/5>-- E
  |2
  |
1 ^3/1
  |
  |
  F
```

Where <2/3> means weight of 2 travelling left and 3 travelling right.
^1/4 means 1 travelling up and 4 travelling down. A single number between two links is the cost of changing links - e.g to go from AD to DF costs 8, and from AB to BE costs 2.

Hope that makes sense...

Simon

(p.s apologies for bad terminology - "links", "edges" - whatever you like ;) )

---

To try and explain the types of weighting better, imagine the edges are train tracks, and the nodes are stations. The cost on the edge is the journey time on a train between two stations, and the costs on the nodes are how long the interchange time is (which may vary between edges even at the same node, depending on how far away the platform is, how regular the service is, etc).

Comment: I'm a little confused by "changing one link(/edge) to another".  Do you mean changing the graph?  For shortest path and traveling salesman, all that matters is weight between nodes.

Comment: What I have here is a weight on passing through each node, as well as a weight on travelling along an edge. Thinking of it as a road system, it's the equivalent of a cost for changing roads, as well as for travelling down one (with nodes being junctions/intersections).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, treat these as two edges instead of one. Then you can use traditional graph theory algorithms on this without a problem, especially if you are always guaranteed to have weights in each direction. These algorithms are easy to find if you are just using a 'normal' graph like I have just helped you create.

You can use [Dijkstra's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) for shortest path.

You can [Prim's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm) for a minimum spanning tree.

You can Google for the asymmetric TSP to try and find an algorithm for that, and I'm pretty sure the *Introduction to Algorithms* has something on this too. Sorry I couldn't find a good implementation of that one for you. There are also a couple of good questions on here about the asymmetric TSP, now that you know it's called the asymmetric TSP.

Good luck! I love graph theory.

-Brian J. Stinar-

Comment: Dijkstra's and Prim's are fine - thanks :) ... As for the Asymmetric TSP, I can only find one question on here, which was closed as "not a real question"... can you link me to one of the "good questions"? Cheers :)

Comment: I'm trying to think through this graph structure with regard to Dijkstra's and Prim's. This is not your typical non-negative weighted graph because it appears to have weighted vertices as well as edges. Is it necessary to distribute the weight on the vertices to the edges first?

Comment: I think that the distribution of weight can be done using a matrix where each row is a vertex weight equation and each colume an edge. Then use gaussian elimination to find the additional weight on the edges.

Comment: I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding what the weight on the vertex itself actually means for this case. I understand that the weight on an edge represents the cost to transition from one vertex to another vertex, using that edge, but what does the weight on the vertex represent? I am also not clear on the suggestion to use Gaussian elimination, do you mean that the actual edge weight equation is simply a sum of edge weight + vertex, and you will calculate this sum for all edges across your adjacency matrix?

Comment: OK, there are actually many good questions about "asymmetric" and about "TSP"... The wikipedia article isn't bad, but I did not actually see an implementation for you. :-( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Asymmetric_TSP

Comment: Think of this like a road system - the edge has the cost of travel down the road, and the node has the cost of changing roads (e.g maybe it takes 1 minute to turn left, but two minutes to turn right).  Having looked at this and thought about it a bit, I have decided that it might be easier to treat each node as multiple nodes (depending on how many edges link to it). For example, D-<4/1>-A(1)-<2/3>-B could be represented as D-<4/1>-A'-<1/1>-A''-<2/3>-B ... if that makes sense? This removes the need to worry about the weighted nodes and it can then be treated as a standard bidirectional graph.

Comment: ...or if you like, the cost on each node is the cost of transitioning between edges.

Comment: Take travelling by train as an example - both sitting on the train, and changing from one train to another, takes time - and both need to be accounted for. One is a cost on an edge (or track), and one is a cost at a node (or station).

Comment: Why not just add this 'node cost' to every edge exiting the node (or whenever the cost in incurred)? Then you can avoid making virtual nodes for this, which would keep it simpler. I think your virtual node idea would work, but it seems like it would make things more complicated than just adding the costs into the edges.

Comment: the problem is the cost is unique depending on two edges - the one you enter the node by, and the one you leave by - thus it can't be added to the exiting edges as you don't know what the previous edge was (there's potentially multiple options)...

Comment: Yeah, I think I see your point now. For lining up with your real world analogy, I would have a vertex from one location to the location where I need to make my turn. There would be an edge between them, with a weight. Then, if I choose to take a left turn, I would have another vertex after the left turn, with the edge between them having the time on the turn. Likewise for the right turn. If I choose to go straight, I would have an edge between my turning decision point and the next destination, with an edge between them with a weight. All the algorithms will expect something like this,

Comment: and it will help people that have used graph theory before help you, since this is how all the textbooks present graphs.

Answer (score 2):

For your "interchange" weights, you can make a little subgraph to encode those.  For example, you have:

```
  |   
  |3  
8 D --
  |2
  |
```

You can encode that using just weights on edges, like this:

```
  |
  |
  D0
  | \3
  |  \
 8|   D2--
  |  /
  | /2
  D1
  |
  |
```

Just watch out for the fact that you don't have to use the 8 edge to get from D0 to D1, as you can go D0->D2->D1 for a weight of 5 instead.  I'm not sure if that is allowed in your original formulation.

Comment: agreed - and it should be fine for what i'm doing; although of course in other examples with a similar problem (such as turning at traffic lights) it would not be.